# Data loss/not working of JSP page when browser refreshed

Tags: jsp, httpsession, http-request

I have created a JSP page, everything is working fine but whenever I refresh the browser I get a message saying

```
   //served at somejsp.jsp
```

I have tried using session attributes in servlets as explained on the internet but no results, any suggestion??? Thanks

Comment: What are the requests the browser issued for the first and second loads?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by using Cookies

Here is what I did in servlet

```
        Cookie loginCookie = new Cookie("username",u.getName());
        Cookie loginCookie1 = new Cookie("userID",h);

        loginCookie.setMaxAge(30*60*60);
        loginCookie1.setMaxAge(30*60*60);
        response.addCookie(loginCookie);
        response.addCookie(loginCookie1);

        response.sendRedirect(".\\userloggedin.jsp");
```

This way I was able to save data on page reload. Thanks